# Can I delete the relative pronoun here?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I want to say, "For the ones who I care and who cares about you." 
Is this admittable to say like this?

And I have one more question to ask.

Can I say, "for the ones I care and who cares about you"?

What I mean is, can I delete `who` in this double relative pronoun sentence?

Comment: What purpose does the image here serve? It doesn't appear to narrow down your question at all, and might be best left out.
Welcome to ELU!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your sentence is currently incorrect. A correct way of phrasing it would be "For those that I care about and that care about you". The reason why you cannot omit the second relative pronoun is that this pronoun is the "object" in the first sentence and the subject of the second sentence. To illustrate this, we could separate this into two sentences and get:

1) Who I care about (I is subject)
2) Who care about you (Who is subject)

Since the subject in these sentences isn't the same, we have to use the relative pronoun twice.

Comment: Oh thanks for your correction! then should i also include "about" in i care <about> part???

Comment: Yep, if the subjects of the two sentences aren't the same then you cannot leave out anything. So unfortunately everything should be written twice :(

Comment: There are a few things here which are not correct. The first _who_ is not ‘the object’ (i.e., the direct object) in the clause it’s in; it’s the object of the preposition _about_. As such, since it’s not subject, it can absolutely be omitted just fine. Only the second _who_ cannot be deleted, since that one is the subject of its clause. “For those I care about and who care about me” is not only perfectly correct but also the most common and natural way to phrase it.